Integration of Legendre polynomials with their derivatives
I need the results of $\int_{-1}^1 p_i(x) p_j'(x) dx$, where $p_i$ is the classical Legendre polynomials in $[-1,1]$. Using the matlab, I get the following result:



i  \  j
0
1
2
3
4




0
0
2
0
2
0


1
0
0
2
0
2


2
0
0
0
2
0


3
0
0
0
0
2


4
0
0
0
0
0



It seems that $\int_{-1}^1 p_{n}(x) p_{n+1+2k}'(x) dx =2 ,\quad n\geq 0,\ k \geq 0$. I am not familiar with Legendre polynomials. If this conclusion is correct, I want to know if there are some theorems to help me get this conclusion easily.

This is only a partial answer and explains all the zeroes in the table, and the first diagonal of $2$s. I will try to update it soon to cover all the cases.
Recall the Legendre polynomials are
$$P_n(x)=\frac1{2^nn!}\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$$
Therefore, for any smooth function $f(x)$,
$$\int_{-1}^1P_n(x)f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
can be evaluated by repeatedly using integration by parts.
$$\int_{-1}^1P_n(x)f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\left[\frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{\mathrm d^{n-1}}{\mathrm dx^{n-1}}(x^2-1)^nf(x)\right]_{-1}^1-\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{\mathrm d^{n-1}}{\mathrm dx^{n-1}}(x^2-1)^nf^{(1)}(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
The first term vanishes and the second term can be again integrated by parts. In the end, you will get
$$\int_{-1}^1P_n(x)f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2^nn!}\int_{-1}^1f^{(n)}(x)(1-x^2)^n\,\mathrm dx$$
Now, if $f(x)=P_m^\prime(x)$ for $m\leq n$, then $P_m^{(n+1)}=0$ so the integral vanishes. Also, $P_m^{(n+1)}$ is an odd function of $x$ if $m-n$ is even. Thus, in that case, we get that
$$\int_{-1}^1P_n(x)P_m^\prime(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$$
If I call the integral $I(n,m)$ (in your notation $I(j,i)$), then so far we have that

$I(n,m)=0$ if $m-n$ is even.
$I(n,m)=0$ if $m\leq n$.

Suppose $m=n+1$, then $P_{n+1}^{(n+1)}(x)$ is simply the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ times $(n+1)!$, which is $\frac{(2n+2)!}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}$. Thus,
$$I(n,n+1)=\frac{(2n+2)!}{2^{2n+1}n!(n+1)!}\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^n\,\mathrm dx$$
The integral is standard (see here). Thus, after easy cancellations, we obtain
$$I(n,n+1)=2$$
So far,

$I(n,m)=0$ if $m-n$ is even.
$I(n,m)=0$ if $m\leq n$.
$I(n,n+1)=2$.


Based on your conclusion, I have derived the remaining part:
What remains is to prove $I(n,n+1+2k) = 2, \  k\geq 1$ .
By
$$
\frac{d}{dx}P_{n+1}(x) = (n+1)P_n(x) + x \frac{d}{dx}P_n(x).
$$
we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
I(n,n+1+2k) & = \int P_{n}((n+1+2k)P_{n+2k}+xP_{n+2k}) , dx  \
& = \int xP_{n}P'{n+2k} , dx \
& = xP{n}P_{n+2k}|{-1}^1 - \int P{n+2k}(P_{n}+xP_{n}') , dx   \
\end{align}
$$
By the fact that $P_n(1) = 1, P_n(-1) = (-1)^n$ and that $xP_n'$ can be expressed by $P_{0},\dots,P_{n}$,  it is esay to obtain
$$
I(n,n+1+2k) = 2.
$$
Thank you!
